# Is this animation of the right hand rule for curl correct?

Tags: calculus, curl

My Calculus text describes positive curl as *counterclockwise* by convention. I found this nice animation of curl:

[image: Curl animation]

Here: https://instruct.math.lsa.umich.edu/lecturedemos/ma215/docs/16_5/examples.html

(Stack exchange appears to have erased that the picture is animated, see original site to observe the rotation)

The site describes curl as satisfying a *right* hand relation.

However I noticed the coordinate system in the illustration is left handed — if I point my left thumb along the positive x-axis my fingers curl from +x to +y — as I understand it the defining feature of a left handed system. Similarly if I point my left thumb in the direction of any of the upwards green curl vectors, it seems to follow the rotation at the given paddle wheel. This would also mean positive rotation is *clockwise* the opposite of what my text says is the convention.

Do the illustration and the description just not match or am I missing something?

Comment: If you change to a left-handed system, it can be convenient to replace the right-hand rule with the left-hand rule. That appears to have been done here.